# Asp display txt from access

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

i got a field that contains txt files in my access database.
i want to display this txt file on my page. how can i read the file and display it exactly as it in file written? In which asp component can i display it? I know some methods to read file but they don't work as i want. my text files have a format and i want to display them so in my page.

Thanks

Comment: Is this inter- or intra- net? What kind of text file? Just plain text with layout or something like Word? Which version of Access? If it is less than 2010, how many users do you expect? I think you will have to add quite a bit more to your question.

Comment: this is asp webapp i mean internet and this is word document. actually i couldn't decide yet. i tried html, word. i don't know how can i do it better yet. And i am using access 2007. 

it works so..
there is a grid list on the page and when i choose one of then a new page will be displayed with details of selected item(image,text as memo) i am getting image and text from access and until this everything works. i changed the memo to ole object and i want to display it as i prepared it.

Comment: I have not tried this, but I think it should work with some tweaking: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173308

Comment: i need to show word or html document not image
i have a template which i use for every page in that template i want to show word or html document. i use binding property of datalist for other things.

Comment: Why are you storing the document in Access? If the document is stored on disk, then it will get a lot easier.

Comment: I would lose the OLE field because it's going to be hard to retrieve the data without the OLE wrapper around it. You might store the data in a memo field, but I'd recommend not storing anything in the database except the path and filename of the stored document, whatever kind of document it happens to be.

Comment: i am storing the Document in Access to make it easier to update documents. this table won't be bigger than 80-100 rows.
i have stored it in a memo before but i have never thought about what David-W-Fenton said. i think it would be more efficient to store the document in disk and path in database. Thanks for your advice everybody.

Comment: by the way, i want to show document(xml or html- which one is better?) in my template. how can i do it? also it will come a document from disk depending to path of selected item its ok but how can i display it in my template? do i need any component or can i call anyway in html tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
it was very easy. i am giving the path to the file and just calling Response.Write(pathToFile)
in template.